# SnmpSharpNet Add User (SNMPv3)

Tags: network-programming, snmp, snmpsharpnet

I'm very simply trying to add a user to the device given the security name, auth key, auth protocol, priv key, and priv protocol using VB.net. At this point, NOT using VB.net is not an option.

SNMPSharpNet does not seem to have a solution for this problem. Open to all and any alternatives. If I would know what OID's to store these values in then I would be all set, so that would be extremely helpful as well. Also open to using the PowerSNMP library.

Comment: We know all of the credentials for this device. How is this not feasible? It's the equivalent of saying "I know my username and password, how do I login?"

Comment: If you notice in my question I say "If I would know what OID's to store these values in then I would be all set". I don't know the OID's or what values to store in the OID's even if I did have them.

Comment: As for them not being equivalent, they are. That's suppose to be the "simplicity with security" behind SNMP version 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to set usmUserStatus + index of new user equal to 4 (CREATE_AND_WAIT) and then set usmUserCloneFrom to usmSecurityName + index of user you want to clone from.